# Short hand if-else returns error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The following JS line of code is not working as I'd expect.

When imageUrl has a value I get the following error and I expect notificationBody to be = "You received a new image message."

What am I missing here?

> invalid value for the "notification.body" property. Values must be
>   strings.

```
const notificationBody = (imageUrl === "" ? "You received a new image message." : messageTxt)
```

message payload:

```
const payload = {
            notification: {
              title: senderName + " sent you a message",
              body: notificationBody
            },
```

entire function:

```
exports.notifyNewMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

  const messageSnap = snap.val(); //snap.after.val();

  const fromId = messageSnap.fromId; 
  const toId = messageSnap.toId; 
  const messageTxt = messageSnap.message; 
  const imageUrl = messageSnap.imageUrl; 

  console.log('fromId: ', fromId);
  console.log('message: ', messageTxt);

  // Get the list of device notification tokens.
  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref('/fcmtokens/' + toId + '/registrationtokens').once('value');

  console.log('getDeviceTokensPromise', getDeviceTokensPromise);


  return admin.database().ref('/fcmtokens/' + toId + '/registrationtokens').once('value').then((userTok) => {

    const registrationTokens = Object.keys(userTok.val())

    console.log('registrationTokens', registrationTokens);


    return admin.database().ref('/users/' + fromId).once('value').then((userDoc) => {

      const user = userDoc.val(); //snap.after.val();

      const senderName = user.firstName //'Vanessa' //userDoc.firstName //get('firstName')
      console.log('senderName: ', senderName);

      const notificationBody = (imageUrl === "" ? "You received a new image message." : messageTxt)

      console.log('imageUrl: ', imageUrl);
      console.log('messageTxt: ', messageTxt);
      console.log('notificationBody: ', notificationBody);

        //build media messages notification
        const payload = {
            notification: {
              title: senderName + " sent you a message",
              body: notificationBody
            },
            data: {
              SENDER_NAME: senderName,
              SENDER_ID: fromId

            }//end data
        }//end payload

        //send message
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload).then( response => {

          const stillRegisteredTokens = registrationTokens

          response.results.forEach((result, index) => {

                    const error = result.error

                    if (error) {

                        const failedRegistrationToken = registrationTokens[index]

                        console.error('blah', failedRegistrationToken, error)

                        if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' || error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {

                                const failedIndex = stillRegisteredTokens.indexOf(failedRegistrationToken)

                                if (failedIndex > -1) {
                                    stillRegisteredTokens.splice(failedIndex, 1)
                                }

                            }
                    }

                })//end forEach

                var  validTokens = {};

                stillRegisteredTokens.forEach(function(element){
                  console.log('valid token: ', element);
                  validTokens[element] = true;
                });
                //updates['registrationtokens'] = stillRegisteredTokens; ....update(updates);

                return admin.database().ref('fcmtokens/' + toId + '/registrationtokens').set(validTokens)

                // return admin.database().ref("fcmtokens/" + toId).update({
                //     //registrationTokens: stillRegisteredTokens
                // })//end update

        })//end sendToDevice


    })//end return-then

  })//end return-then

});
```

Comment: So were are you settings `notification.body`, as your code here shows `notificationBody`, so this doesn't look like the line the error is coming from.

Comment: i've updated my question to include the code that specifies the `body`

Comment: There's a very high likelihood that messageTxt's value is not a string, if this piece of code is what's causing your error

Comment: There will be something using the `payload`, it will be that what's throwing the error.  It's basically saying whatever values you having in `payload.notification.body`, is not a string.

Comment: Is it possible that `body: notificationBody` is evaluating before `notificationBody` is assigned a value?

Comment: I've included my entire function, as far as I can see I am not changing `notificationBody` anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

First, it looks like if `imageUrl` is not "" then `notificationBody` will be the value of `messageTxt`, not the "You received a new image message." string.

The javascript ternary statement works this way:

```
const foo = (<conditional> ? <value if conditional is True> : <value if conditional is False>)
```

Second, are you sure your example code is exactly the same as the code you are getting the error with? I see no reference to `notification.body` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Your ternary isn't doing what you expect, the first case is for true, the second is for false, so you could either switch around your cases, or in my solution below, switch the comparison operator to `!==`

What I suspect is happening in your code, because your ternary is incorrect, is that you don't have a value set for `messageTxt`, and so it's passing `undefined` into your `payload` as the value of `body`

I'd also highly suggest using `JSON.stringify()` around your `payload` if you're not doing that already.

#### Solution

```js
const senderName = 'tacocat';
const imageUrl = 'something';
const messageTxt = 4815162342

const notificationBody = (
  imageUrl !== "" ?
  "You received a new image message." :
  messageTxt
)

const payload = JSON.stringify({
  notification: {
    title: senderName + " sent you a message",
    body: notificationBody
  }
})
console.log(payload)
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator